# Limit of a nonnegative sequence of real numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(x_n)$ a sequence of real numbers nonnegative so that $$x_{n+1}\leq x_n+\frac{1}{n^2}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{for all}\,\, n\in\mathbb{N}$$

Show that exist $$\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n$$

Comment: $|x_{n+1}-x_n|\leq\dfrac 1{n^2}\to 0$

Comment: is this so obvious? Of course $x_{n+1}-x_n\leq 1/n^2$. But from below you get the bound $x_{n+1}-x_n\geq -x_n$ at least at a first step. For increasing sequences your claim is clear. What about non-decreasing or oscillating ones? For example the sequence $x_1=10, x_n=0$ for $n\geq 2$ does not fulfill the estimate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\left\{x_n + \dfrac{1}{n-1}\right\}_{n=2}^\infty$ is positive and monotonically decreases.

> $$x_{n+1}+\frac1n \leq x_n+\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac1n < x_n+\frac{1}{n-1}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Let us generalize the statement to be proved to make it easier to prove, thus, let us assume that $(x_n)$ is a nonnegative sequence such that $x_{n+1}\leqslant x_n+a_n$ for every $n$, for some nonnegative sequence $(a_n)$ such that $\sum\limits_na_n$ converges.

Then $y_n=x_n+\sum\limits_{k\geqslant n}a_k$ defines a finitely valued (can you show it?) nonincreasing (can you show it?) nonnegative (can you show it?) sequence $(y_n)$. Thus $(y_n)$ converges to some nonnegative limit $\ell$ when $n\to\infty$. But $____$ $\to0$ hence $x_n\to\ell$ as well.

Answer (score -1):

Let's $m > n$:

\begin{align}
\left\vert x_{m} - x_{n}\right\vert
&=
\left\vert\left(x_{m} - x_{m - 1}\right) + \left(x_{m - 1} - x_{m - 2}\right)
+
\cdots
+
\left(x_{n + 1} - x_{n}\right)
\right\vert
\leq
\sum_{k = n}^{m - 1}\left\vert x_{k + 1} - x_{k}\right\vert
\leq
\sum_{k = n}^{m - 1}{1 \over k^{2}}
\\[3mm]&<
\int_{n - 1}^{m - 1}{{\rm d}x \over x^{2}}
=
{m - n \over \left(m - 1\right)\left(n - 1\right)}
<
{1 \over n - 1}
\\[5mm]&
\end{align}

Given $\epsilon > 0\,,\quad$
$\left\vert x_{m} - x_{n}\right\vert < \epsilon\quad\forall\ m, n > N$
where $N \equiv \left\lfloor 1 + 1/\epsilon\right\rfloor$.

Comment: as i commented above, why is the absolute value of the difference of two consecutive elements bounded and in particular bounded by $1/k^2$ ? I'm unfortunately not seeing this

Comment: OP posts wrong answer. Is told politely why answer is wrong. Does not modify answer (does not even react to comment). *Ottimo!*